# How to comment out entire php code from beginning to end?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a default code in Wordpress which I want to get rid of but don't necessarily want to fully delete forever:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) : ?>

<div class="sidebar fright" role="complementary">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>

</div><!-- .sidebar -->

<?php else : ?>

<div class="sidebar fright" role="complementary">

    <div id="search" class="widget widget_search">

        <div class="widget-content">

            <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        </div>

    </div><!-- .widget_search -->

    <div class="widget widget_recent_entries">

        <div class="widget-content">

            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e("Latest posts", "baskerville") ?></h3>

            <ul>
                <?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"]) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"] . '</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- .widget_recent_entries -->

    <div class="widget widget_text">

        <div class="widget-content">

            <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( "Text widget", "baskerville" ); ?></h3>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- .widget_recent_entries -->

</div><!-- .sidebar -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I comment out the entire code? If I simply do < folowed by !-- at the very beginning and --> at the end it doesn't work.

Comment: PHP isn't commented with `<!-- -->` try `/* multiple lines of code */` instead

Comment: You mean /* at the beginning and */ at the end would work? Because it doesn't. Or I have to do this for each and every line? I want a whole wrapper for commenting everything. Is it possible?

Comment: Check the answer I added. It works for multiple lines, but it won't work correctly if you have pure HTML not enclosed by PHP tags

Comment: Why not just copy the file, rename the original file as `sidebar.backup.php` and make your modifications on the copy? This way, if you ever need to restore the original file you can just rename it back to `sidebar.php` and be done with it.

Comment: You mean to copy it in somewhere else? Because I don't know if it is possible to copy it & put it in Wordpress itself.

Comment: Are you editing `sidebar.php` directly on WordPress? If so, you could just copy the contents of the original file and save it somewhere (a .txt file on your desktop, a draft e-mail on your inbox, dropbox, etc) and then add your changes to the original `sidebar.php`. It would be better if you didn't edit files via the WordPress editor though: if you break something you might get locked out of the admin interface, and believe me that's not fun at all - especially if you're working on a live site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard PHP commenting syntax is:

`// comment` for one-liners

`/* multiple lines of code */` for multiple lines

Be aware that you may encounter some erratic behaviour if you have a mix of PHP and pure HTML not enclosed within PHP tags as `/* blah */` will inhibit the PHP interpreter from doing its work with the code that's actually enclosed in PHP tags but will not comment out pure HTML, which the snip of code you wish to leave out does have

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly should I do in my case then? Comment each of them separately? That can be very ugly if there are a lot of HTML inside PHP and vice-versa codes.

Comment: the best practice would be to remove the whole block of code as leaving commented code which is not intended to be used is generally a bad idea. You could "hack" this by enclosing everything on the original code with PHP tags and then commenting everything. It's a bit ugly but it should work. See this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9aa9705827f9307d47b29952ecc057d4b0153bec

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be mega hacky, just change below lines

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) : ?>
```

becomes

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'something_youre_never_ever_going_to_call_a_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
```

This means this whole section of code will never get hit!